# Is it possible to find the magnetic field at an axial point due a current carrying disk?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I started off using Biot Savart Law,but couldn't find any information about which element(dl) to choose,etc.Also I think magnetic field should depend upon the direction in which current is flowing...
Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using amperes law.  Don't forget you'll have a double integral because the distance from the incremental current loop is changing while incremental current loop is expanding over your disk. Don't forget the current vector has a cross product with the distance vector.